# Order by date and group by id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-order-by

I have a list of events in `events_table`, i store date of event in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.
I need to sort events by date:

```
(SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY date DESC)
```

But if I have more then 1 events on similar date, sorting works wrong.
**I want to sort by date and by id, to view correct order(new events first).**

I know that good practice is to use a `timestamp`, but since users can introduce information about event that was a day or two ago and this method not working in my case.

Comment: `SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY date DESC, id desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want first descending order by date and then ascending order by id then use below-

```
SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC;
```

If you want first descending order by date and then descending order by id then use below-

```
SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY date DESC, id Desc;
```

If if id is primary key and auto_increment then there is no need to use ordering on date as ordering on id will be enough and will be more optimized.

```
SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY id Desc;
```

Comment: It does not mean that the event date will increase as with id. For every new entry into the table event dates may not be in the ascending order like auto ids. Event dates can be like 'curdate()`, `a date falling 5 days later`, `a date falling 2 days later' etc., which are not in the asc order.

Comment: @Ravinder: Your are right, it will depend on user's requirement..as per user requirement here he is storing even date means if any even will occur then latest event's id will be higher if id is auto_increment....other wise other options are there as per user requirement.

Comment: @marakesh: If your date column is of `varchar` type and values are stored in `dd-mm-yyyy`, or `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd.mm.yyyy` format, then this solution is not going to work.

Comment: @Ravinder my date column is date type, dates are stored in yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @marakesh: It is good that you clarified, though late, by updating the post. Cheer up.

Answer (score 0):

You can ORDER BY multiple fields.

```
SELECT * from events_table ORDER BY date DESC, id;
```